# Using 'is' to check runtime type of Dart generic

Tags: generics, dart

I'm relatively new to Dart and am trying to model an algebraic data type (like Swift's enums with associated values).

When I attempt to check the runtime type of a value, though, I'm seeing some behaviour that I don't really understand. Consider the following code:

```
abstract class Fetchable<T> {
  factory Fetchable.success(T object) = FetchableSuccess;
  factory Fetchable.error(Error error) = FetchableError;
}
class FetchableSuccess<T> implements Fetchable<T> {
  final T object;
  const FetchableSuccess(this.object);
}
class FetchableError<T> implements Fetchable<T> {
  final Error error;
  const FetchableError(this.error);
}

void main() {
  // ------------- CASE 1 -------------
  final s = Fetchable.success("hi there");
  print(s.runtimeType);                             // FetchableSuccess<dynamic>
  print(s is FetchableSuccess);                     // true
  print(s is FetchableSuccess<String>);             // false
  print(s is FetchableSuccess<dynamic>);            // true

  if (s is FetchableSuccess) {
    print(s.object);                                // compile error 
  }
  if (s is FetchableSuccess<dynamic>) {
    print(s.object);                                // compile error
  }

  // ------------- CASE 2 -------------
  final e = Fetchable.error(StateError("uh oh"));
  print(e is FetchableError);                       // true
  if (e is FetchableError) {
    print(e.error);                                 // Works OK
  }
}
```

As you can see, I create two cases... I just can't seem to extract the `object` variable from the `success` case. The `is` keyword tells me that it is a `FetchableSuccess<dynamic>` (which seems odd... I thought that Dart doesn't erase the type? I would have expected it to be a `FetchableSuccess<String>`)

Even then, though, if I cast to `FetchableSuccess<dynamic>` the compiler still tells me it doesn't know about the `object` variable in the `FetchableSuccess` subclass.

Contrast that, though, to `FetchableError` (which doesn't explicitly use a value of type `T`)... `is` works correctly and the compiler is able to access the `error` variable.

What am I missing? Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a couple of issues here: First, you need to add `<T>` to the right hand sides of the two factory constructors.

If you do that the run-time type of `s` will be `ReflectableSucces<String>` as it should be, and you'll get `true` from the following 3 lines in `main`.

Then you're testing `s is FetchableSuccess` which means `s is FetchableSuccess<dynamic>`, and that's not a subtype of the statically known type `Fetchable<String>` so you don't get promotion (so there is no `object` getter in the static type, hence the error). Testing `s is FetchableSucces<dynamic>` explicitly is of course subject to the same treatment.

So the remaining question is, why don't you get an error for those missing `<T>`s? I'm searching issues for that now, it is probably a known bug.

Update: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/34714 addresses the fact that inference is not done in the common front end even though it should. So we get the analysis using inference from the analyzer, and then we get the semantics at run time which does not use inference (and thus defaults to `<dynamic>`), and that's the reason why we get this unfortunate clash where the actual type argument is wrong at run time, and there is no compile-time error. It should be resolved when said issue is landed.

Comment: Wonderful! As you suggested, adding the trailing `<T>` to the factory constructor so that it looks like `factory Fetchable.success(T object) = FetchableSuccess<T>;` makes everything work at runtime as I'd expect. Thanks so much for the nudge in the right direction... much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I agree, this is really weird. The short explanation: the type is inferred as `Fetable<String>`, so here are three fun ways to work around it:

```
var a = Fetchable.success("hi there");
if (a is FetchableSuccess<String>) {
  print(a.object);                                // fine
}

var b = Fetchable<dynamic>.success("hi there");
if (b is FetchableSuccess) {
  print(b.object);                                // fine
}

var c = Fetchable.success("hi there" as dynamic);
if (c is FetchableSuccess) {
  print(c.object);                                // fine
}
```

I'll send email to the language folks to see if they have thoughts.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. Alas, while your first case compiles, the `if` condition fails at runtime. The second two cases look like they will work OK... the only challenge is that it makes the type variable declaration much more complicated. I'll do some more exploration down this path...